# C# - Problem with System.Timer Tick Eventhandling

Tags: c#, events, timer, event-handling, progress-bar

I've got a problem while programming a little game for myself. 
I'm using the "System.Timers"-Timer and want to decrease the value of a progress bar 
by every tick of the timer. There I faced my problem. I can't set a custom event handler to decrease the value of the progress bar.

I've using for the Timer the following code:

```
private Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 600000;
t.Elapsed += Ended; //For ending event
t.AutoReset = true;
```

So how can I register a tick to decrease the value of the progress bar.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Greetings
SirCodiac

Comment: You need to set a different timer for a smaller interval and write a different handler that updates the progress bar. Which part of this isn't clear to you?

Answer (score 0):

You cant invoke a control from system.timers. In order to invoke the progress bar either use System.Windows.Forms.Timer or use a MethodInvoker as below:

```
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        progressBar1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { progressBar1.Value++; }));
    }
    else
    {
        progressBar1.Value++;
    }

}
```